# Trouble modifying .bashrc file to alllow sublime text 2 in git-bash

Tags: bash, git, sublime-text-2

I would like to change or add the ability to open files when working with mingw32 with a different text editor (in my case sublime text 2).

I would like to be able to do the following from the command line:

```
$ sublime_text textfile.text -- where st is a command to use st2 to open the textfile.
```

you can already do this with vim

so following [Git for Windows: .bashrc or equivalent config files for Git Bash shell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6883760/1727263) , I have created a .bashrc file and put:

```
export EDITOR=/c/Users/bill/Desktop/f/st/sublime_text1
```

Inside. however even after closing and opening the window the command:

```
bill@PC /c/users/bill/desktop/f
$ sublime_text1 hello
sh.exe": sublime_text1: command not found
```

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are doing two different things here:

```
export EDITOR=/c/Users/bill/Desktop/f/st/sublime_text1
```

If other applications need to open a text editor (e.g. git, to edit a commit message), they will use the one specified in the `EDITOR` environment variable.

```
$ sublime_text1 hello
```

Now you want to run Sublime Text from the command line.  There are two ways you can do that without having to always specify the full path: either use an alias:

```
$ alias sublime_text='/c/Users/bill/Desktop/f/st/sublime_text1'
$ sublime_text hello
```

or add Sublime Text's directory to the `PATH`:

```
$ PATH="/c/Users/bill/Desktop/f/st:$PATH"
$ sublime_text1 hello
```

Note that aliases are only available inside the shell, so they won't work if you try to run them from inside another application (e.g. vim).

Comment: Thanks, I used the path. Is this the same path as in the win 7 path environmental variable?

Comment: @user61629 The function and contents are the same. The only changes are that `;` separates directories on Windows (`:` on Cygwin) and (obviously) the paths' formatting.